# SharePoint 2010 Standard and Forms

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, infopath, licensing

We have a Standard Server License of SharePoint 2010 and we want to develop Infopath form.

I need a tutorial or directions in bullet points as to what should I do to achieve this. I've heard in Standard edition that we can't use InfoPath but I read that one can do it like creating list and modifying forms using SharePoint 2010 Designer. 
Is it possible this way? If yes, then guide me.

Answer (score 3):

Here you can find some detailed info on licensing requirements for InfoPath forms:

http://blog.sharepointelearning.com/licensing-requirements-for-infopath-forms-on-sharepoint/

If you are looking for some basic guidelines on how to develop workflow in SharePoint Designer and how to use InfoPath forms I think this link can be useful:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=695

But you don't need InfoPath for developing workflow forms because you can use standard ASP.NET forms designed in Sharepoint Designer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454098.aspx

For more advanced scenarios you will need to use Visual Studio. Here is how to do it with InfoPath (enterprise licence is required):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms564355.aspx

Answer (score 1):

OMG, I am surprised that the questioner took for granted, [according to his comment](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17022/sharepoint-2010-standard-and-forms#comment13594_17023) from Jul 31 2011, the [completely misleading and wrong answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/17023/8319) (every phrase of which is wrong), having ignored  link in [another answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/17025/8319) from Jul 30, 2011 with quite exhaustive considerations:

- Asif's SharePoint Blog. [Licensing requirements for InfoPath forms on SharePoint](http://blog.sharepoint-videos.com/licensing-requirements-for-infopath-forms-on-sharepoint/)

> Customizing standard list forms, or publishing forms to a form library
>   requires Enterprise.

Enterprise Sharepoint is required only for running Infopath forms through IPFS - Sharepoint Server Infopath Form Services, i.e. opening them in browser. It is not required for opening IP forms in Infopath Filler (on client machines).  **Even if one has enterprize Sharepoint Server, using only Filler/client forms is in most cases more preferable since they have richer UI features vs. very restricted and limited web- or browser forms!**

It is possible to publish IP forms into Sharepoint libraries (in Infopath Designer), customize Infopath forms and open them from sharepoint libraries locally, on client machines,  in Infoapth Filler though it require installing Infopath on all client machines. Though it rarely a restriction as Sharepoint is mostly used in intranets and enterprise environments having Microsoft Office suite installed anyway.

Besides it is possible to use Infopath forms:

- both without Sharepoint
- or publishing them to client machines using only Sharepoint Foundation

Also, to note, that one can use enterprise Sharepoint Server without owning or having a SP server through cloud [Sharepoint Online](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_365#Microsoft_SharePoint_Online) as part of [Microsoft Office 365](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_365) subscription plans.

Answer (score 0):

InfoPath forms are only licensed on Standard Edition for workflow forms. Customizing standard list forms, or publishing forms to a form library requires Enterprise.

Comment: My Form will based on Mutilevel Approval workflow so it means i can use infopath? Secondly, if I cant publish then how can I make it available for users? what are the steps of doing it
1. ?
2. ?
3. ?

Comment: "InfoPath forms are only licensed on Standard Edition for workflow forms"... do you have an official link for this statement ?

Comment: I'm not sure about an "offical" document, but it is correct.  You can edit/create workflow forms with InfoPath in Standard.  With Enterprise you get the ability to host your forms in a form library.

Comment: Well Jesus exactly this is what I wanted to say...thanks...now what to do