# SP 2013 Foundations: Form Library Only Working For Domain Admins?

Tags: infopath

I have an Infopath form that I have published to my SP 2013 foundations site. More specifically the form was published to a form library app called Expense Reports.

If a domain admin clicks on "new document" in the Expense Reports app, it pulls up the form in Infopath on their computer. If any other non domain admin clicks new document, they get the upload file dialog box as seen in the attached pictures.

(apparently I can't post pictures yet. The dialog box looks like the one that shows up when you want to upload a file to a document library)

I added this infopath template using the below method

> ```
> Deploy an InfoPath form template to a SharePoint form library
> ```
>
> The simplest and quickest way to deploy an InfoPath form template is
>   to a SharePoint form library.
>
> You can deploy an InfoPath form template in one of two ways to a
>   SharePoint form library:
>
> Create a SharePoint form library from within InfoPath when publishing
>   the form template to SharePoint. Pre-create a SharePoint form library
>   in SharePoint and then update the InfoPath form template of an
>   existing SharePoint form library from within InfoPath.

Any ideas? Foundations should be able to open the form right? I'm not trying to embed the form on the page, which I understood would require Enterprise.

According to @Luis Carvalho in [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20125/infopath-with-sharepoint-foundation-2010) post, it sounds like what I'm asking should be possible.

If you need any more information, please let me know!

Comment: do all other users have InfoPath installed on their machine?

Comment: Yes. Mix of 2007 and 2010 users. On the SP site itself, I've given some users full control permission as a test, had them click the link, and as described above what pops up is the upload file box, instead of the infopath form.