# Infopath Form use in SharePoint Module Need License?

Tags: infopath, licence

I Created Custom State Machine Workflow in that workflow having Infopath Custom Form Module so we are going to deploy in production server. This Application access number end users in that time we need any Infopath License Please help............

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could understand what you are asking about. License (or [free license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_license)) is used and needed even for [freeware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeware) products.

Infopath is part of Microsoft Office that is commercial product and generally not free. Though, the cost of license has nothing to do with the need of having licenses for software usage, be they free or not, in Sharepoint module or not.

**Update:**
Please check [my answer on Sharepoint - Infopath licensing and usage](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17022/sharepoint-2010-standard-and-forms/57858#57858)

Once more, the licensing depends on how you usу Infopath forms with Sharepoint:

- are you using Sharepoint Online or own your own enterprse Sharepoint server
- restrict the usage of Infopath forms to filler/client (non-browser-enabled forms) or use browser-enabled forms
- publish to Sharepoint server or to client machines using free Sharepoint Foundation
- etc.

Anyway, with enterprise, standard Sharepoint server or "free" Sharepoint Foundation, with client Infopath or through IPFS, one cannot avoid purchasing Microsoft licenses since it is hooked to using Windows operating system on every client machine. Additional options with Sharepoint and Infopath depend.

Your question is impossible to answer without knowing your details or requirements

Comment: Module incense Custom Task Form need license in all end users PC's?

Comment: If you access and use server components through installed on client machines client software, like Infopath Filler, then yes. Though, this depends both on your client MS Office licence and Sharepoint Server licence. As well as on how client and server components are configured and used.

Comment: Updated my answer